# Toast wont show up on SMS app

Tags: android, sms, toast

I have a problem, not that major problem but since i implemented sendMultipartTextMessage on my codes the toast of "SMS Sent" or any other toast wont show up. I dunno if the sms is successfully sent or not. What should I do? Here's the code:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message, boolean split)
    {      
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        if (!split) {
            Log.d("SMSTest", "Sending single message: " + message);
        } else {
            Log.d("SMSTest", "Sending '" + message + "' in multiple parts.");
            ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
            Log.d("SMSTest", parts.size() + " parts:");
            for (String string : parts) {
                Log.d("SMSTest", string);
            }    
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                    sentList.add(sentPI);
                    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                    deliveredList.add(deliveredPI);
                    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, sentList,
                            deliveredList);

                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;                      
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));   
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: put a default: in switch and check if any of the conditions are true or not.

Comment: did you change definition of `sentPi` and `deliveredPI` compared to [example](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)  you are using?

Comment: Just edited the code and the whole sms methods are posted.

Comment: seems right except for `if (!split)` clause - if `split` is `false` you are not sending anything at all. btw, what device are you testing it on?

Comment: LG-p350 is my device. the if(!split) checks if in sending multipart message if not its just a single message. Well from the emulator its just "sending single message: nieklm" and no toast is prompted.

Comment: well the code you provided does not send single messages. it only prints to debug log

Comment: if i take out the "!" it ends with error to nullpointererror, what should i do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never implement a switch without default case. Make one and display the value of `getResultCode()`, than you might see at least what is returned. This should help you investigate the behavior further.

Sample:

```
switch (getResultCode()) {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    default:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Default... " + getResultCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: How should i do this default?